# chrome and problem with the JS with statement

Tags: javascript, with-statement

I have a code like this:

```
with(document.formname) {
  if(item("fieldname").value==1) {
    alert("Good");
  }
}
```

it works fine in IE but chrome gives me undifend for the **item**

what i want to know is if there is a way to work with it?
if not, how do i build a dynamic document.formname.fieldname+i.value

i need it to be to the field name and not to and ID with a getelementbyID

in addition this code is in a modaldialog and not window popup
and the i can be any number

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, but what about document.formname["fieldname"]?

Comment: The "with" statement is a really bad idea.  You should post the HTML involved.